# how to update data when selecting

Tags: mysql

There is a table named DTable, new data is flushing into it every 10mins. I want to select some data and flag the newly selected data so that they cannot be selected from then on. I used to select the records first, then flag them. But this approach is not perfect. Can I use one query to achieve that goal?

Comment: Take a look here. http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/select-update-single-statement-race-condition

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what i want. The trouble is, for example, select one field of data and flag the records by another field. Table may like this
`create table DTable 
(id int auto_increment  primary key,
data varchar(20) not null,
flag tinyint default 0)`
there's many records, and I want to select 100 recods randomly, and flag them so I can get rid of them at the next selection.